# receive sms broadcast after clear ram

Tags: android

i know this question may be asked by another user ...but i can not solve my problem
i create one broadcast for receive sms and it worked well but when user clear ram broadcast does not work ...
how i can create a broadcast that work even user clear ram
it is my code

```
public class ReceiveSms extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("log","sms received");
    //    Toast.makeText(App.context,"you have sms",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Object[] pdus= (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");


        SmsMessage sms=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
        String body=sms.getMessageBody();
        String sender=sms.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
        Log.i("log","sms body"+body);
        Toast.makeText(App.context,"message from :"+sender,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent startProgram=new Intent(App.context,MainActivity.class);
        startProgram.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        App.context.startActivity(startProgram);


    }


}
```

and mainfast

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.masiha68.sms">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".RC"
            android:process=":remote"
            android:enabled="true"
            >

        </service>

<receiver android:name=".ReceiveSms"
    android:process=":remote"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED">

        </action>
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In huawei device, you need to enable you app in 'Protected apps' to keep running after the screen off or after you kill app from background.

For that goto,

Phone Manager -> Power saving -> Protected apps -> find your app and 'enable' it.